# Updating the balance of after each withdrawal or deposit

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and have been working on this project for a bit. I have fixed my previous issues and finished a working program. However, I am stuck on a new issue now. I have a banking program that withdraws or deposits and adds to the initial balance. However, I can not update to the new balance after that initial deposit or withdraw.

TL;DR: initial balance = 1000. do a deposit of 100. new balance = 1100. Do another deposit of 100 and it will not update and the balance will stay at 1100.

**Account.cs**

```
namespace Account_Teller
{
    class Account
   {   

    private decimal _amount;
    public decimal balance;

    public decimal Balance { get; }

    public Account (decimal pBalance)
    {
        this.Balance = pBalance;
    }

    public decimal Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return _amount;              
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Please enter an amount greater than 0");                  
            }
            else
            {
                _amount = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal Deposit()
    {          
        balance = Balance + _amount;
        return balance;
    }

    public decimal Withdrawl()
    {                    

        balance = Balance - _amount;


        if (balance < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Withdrawing " + _amount.ToString("C") + " would leave you overdrawn!");
        }
        return balance;
    }
}
```

}

**Main.cs**

```
namespace Account_Teller
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Account acc = new Account(1000);


    private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblBalance.Text = acc.Balance.ToString("C");
        try
        {               
            acc.Amount = decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text);               
            lblBalance.Text = acc.Withdrawl().ToString("C");               
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        } 
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            acc.Amount = decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text);                
            lblBalance.Text = acc.Deposit().ToString("C");
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }    
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblBalance.Text = acc.Balance.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So have you stepped through each line of code in the debugger, and examined the variables, etc?  That is Step #1.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I've examined the variables and tried debugging. Fairly new to C# so I'm not sure how to examine the methods with debugging. I've run through debugging and it showed me the steps but I'm still not sure how to update to the new balance.

Comment: The problem is that you've got three different variables , `balance`, `_amount`, and `Balance` trying to track the same thing and you're not updating them all. For example, `Deposit` updates `balance` but not `Balance`. This is insane, use one variable.

Comment: @DourHighArch Yeah I understand that. Would be a lot easier if I wasn't required to have the Balance field read-only.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your code that ties the property `Balance` to the field `balance`. As far as C# is concerned they are two separate variables.

Your `Balance` should probably be defined as:

```
public decimal Balance { get; private set; }
```

Then you would not have a `balance` field at all.

The rest of your class should really look like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

    public Account(decimal balance)
    {
        this.Balance = balance;
    }

    public void Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0m)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Please enter an amount greater than 0");
        }
        this.Balance = this.Balance + amount;
    }

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        if (this.Balance - amount < 0m)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Withdrawing " + amount.ToString("C") + " would leave you overdrawn!");
        }
        this.Balance = this.Balance - amount;
    }
}
```

That would be a more typical implementation of this code.

You would then write this kind of code to use the class:

```
acc.Withdraw(decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text));
lblBalance.Text = acc.Balance.ToString("C");
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have not set constraints between balance and Balance. And one thing, don't expose balance as public

```
class Account
    {

        private decimal _amount;
        private decimal _balance;

        public decimal Balance
        {
            get { return _balance; }
            private set { _balance = value; }
        }

        public Account(decimal pBalance)
        {
            this.Balance = pBalance;
        }

        public decimal Amount
        {
            get { return _amount; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Please enter an amount greater than 0");
                }
                else
                {
                    _amount = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public decimal Deposit()
        {
            _balance = _balance + _amount;
            return _balance;
        }

        public decimal Withdrawl()
        {
            if (_balance - _amount < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Withdrawing " + _amount.ToString("C") + " would leave you overdrawn!");
            }
            _balance = _balance - _amount;
            return _balance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. I've actually attempted this myself but is the Balance field still considered a read-only even by adding private before the set?

Comment: private set on Balance mean that it is impossible to set Balance directly form outside Account class. Yes, it is considered as read-only